# How to access collection and documents within it in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

So, basically I have started bulding new app with React, Redux and Firebase.
I am still learning and am not able to solve some things but this is the first moment, when I am really stuck.

I have created a collection in the Firestore called 'posts' and created one post manually just to see if it is working.

Unfortunately, after implementing my code I keep receiving an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined
AdminpanelAuth.componentDidMount
/src/components/Admin/Adminpanel.js:23
  20 |    componentDidMount() {
  21 |        this.setState({ loading: true });
  22 | 
> 23 |        this.props.firebase.posts().on('value', snapshot => { <- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

I have tried different variations and different approaches but none of them seemed to be working. Could anyone advise? Below I am attaching a part of my code of Adminpanel.js and Firebase.js

Firebase.js

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    my config here
  };

  class Firebase {
    constructor() {
      app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      // initialize Firebase Authenticator
      this.auth = app.auth();
      // initialize Firebase Realtime Database
      this.db = app.firestore();

    }

    // Initialize two functions that connect to Firebase : Log In and Log Out

    doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    doSignOut = () => this.auth.signOut();

    // Initialize functions for posts

    post = pid => this.db.doc('posts'+pid);
    posts = () => this.db.collection('posts');
  }


export default Firebase;
```

Adminpanel.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'recompose'
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'
import { withAuthorisation } from '../Session'
import SignOutBtn from '../SignOutBtn'

const Adminpanel = ({authUser}) => (
<div>{authUser ? <AdminpanelAuth /> : <AdminpanelNonAuth />}</div>
)

class AdminpanelAuth extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading:false,
            posts:[]
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });

        this.props.firebase.posts().on('value', snapshot => {
      const postsObject = snapshot.val();

      const postsList = Object.keys(postsObject).map(key => ({
        ...postsObject[key],
        pid: key,
      }));

      this.setState({
        posts: postsList,
        loading: false,
      });
        });
    }
```

./Firebase/index.js

```
import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './context';
import Firebase from './Firebase';

export default Firebase;

export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase };
```

Comment: I think I am exporting something wrongly but I cannot see where

Comment: what about `this.props.Firebase.posts()...`

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: So, `Firebase.js` is a JS Class, not a react component yes?

Comment: It's a component where I initialize firebase with the whole react project

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though your problem might be that you are trying to access your `Firebase` class through props when it needs to be instantiated in your `Adminpanel` component.

In your imports you have:

```
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'
```

Which looks as though you are trying to use an HOC but looking at `Firebase.js`, there is no indication of you passing a component in, to then pass `props` to.

Instead, in your `Adminpanel` component, try changing your import to:

```
import Firebase from '../Firebase'
```

Then, in the constructor of `Adminpanel`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading:false,
        posts:[]
    }
  this.firebase = new Firebase()
}
```

Then, try to call the class method by doing:

```
this.firebase.posts().on('value', snapshot => {
```

Comment: You might be actually right, I'll check if this works within the next hour and let you know. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have got it in my Firebase context.js, so I believe it is definitely included properly.
It is not a fault of HOC :(

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries?

Comment: I am using react libraries (router, redux, redux-thunk and recompose)

I am wrapping up components with the other HOC components and I believe there is the problem, as everywhere else in the other normal components I am able to access this.props.firebase but not in that particular one.

Comment: I will push src code to GitHub and maybe it would give you a broader view on what's going on.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll see if I can gather anything from it.

Comment: here is the source code https://github.com/szygendaborys/LiderAPP

Thanks for your help :)